# SQL Server 2008 Configuration For Client Server VB.NET (Windows Form) Application

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

**Case :**

I'm creating an application (desktop application) with VB.NET (actually windows form), and using SQL Server Express 2008 for its database.

---

**Problem :**

I wanted to create a client-server application, it means i just need 1 database in server.
Let's go to the real problem. I have a computer and a laptop. I set my laptop's IP : 192.168.1.1 and my computer's IP : 192.168.1.2

Now, i place the database in my computer (192.168.1.2), the database name is db_transportasi.
Problem is, i want to connect from my laptop (192.168.1.1) to my computer database. With LAN of course (i've set up all the network stuff)

---

**Specification :**

I'm using this string below for my connection :

```
Dim connString As String = "Data Source=ARVID-THEODORUS\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB_TRANSPORTASI;Integrated Security=True"
```

Here is the SQL Server SS :
[image: SQL Server First Connect]

---

**Question :**

1. What should i do with SQL Server 2008 in my laptop? Should i configure something or i simply click "connect" as i usually do?
2. What should i change from the connection string above? Should i change the connection string in my computer? Or only in laptop?

Thanks before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check, if the SQL Server instance on your computer has the tcp and/or named pipes protocol enabled (see the configuration tool in your computers start menu under the sql server folder). Then you should probably open the corrsponding tcp port in your computers firewall (1433/tcp or 1434/tcp). Finally you will probably have to change your connection string on your laptop. Since you did not mention any domain structure, integrated security will not work for you. Confugure your Sql Server instance to use mixed authentication mode and create a sql server login you can use in your application.

Comment: could you give me a connection string example for my laptop?